# CHAR16_T type definition in matrix.h. Trying to read Mat-Files

Tags: c++, matlab, qt, mat-file

I am trying to read mat-files in C++ in a Qt project. At morning I had next problem: [Read Mat Files in C++ in a Qt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35271014/read-mat-files-in-c-in-a-qt-project), and it is solved already. But now I am having problems with the next issue:

```
matrix.h:267: error: C2146: syntasis error :';'is missing before 'mxChar'
c4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. note c++ does not support default-int
```

In my project.pro I am telling it:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -EHsc -std=c++11 -Zc:wchar_t
QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -std=c++11
```

In the tmwtypes.h where types are defined:

```
/** UTF-16 character type */

#if (defined(__cplusplus) && (__cplusplus >= 201103L)) || (defined(_HAS_CHAR16_T_LANGUAGE_SUPPORT) && _HAS_CHAR16_T_LANGUAGE_SUPPORT)
typedef UINT16_T CHAR16_T;
#define U16_STRING_LITERAL_PREFIX u
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
typedef wchar_t CHAR16_T;
#define U16_STRING_LITERAL_PREFIX L
#else
typedef UINT16_T CHAR16_T;
#endif

#endif  /* __TMWTYPES__ */

#endif /* tmwtypes_h */
```

In the matrix.h:

```
/*
 * Logical type
 */
typedef bool mxLogical;

/*
 * Typedef required for Unicode support in MATLAB
 */
typedef CHAR16_T mxChar;
```

Thanks in advance,and sorry if it is a amateur question.

Comment: 3 questions: (1) which compiler are you using? (2) does `matrix.h` actually include `tmwtypes.h`? (3) does the type which you map to `CHAR16_T` actually exist, i.e. is it defined by the compiler or another header you are including?

Comment: I'd run the preprocessor on this to see which branch is actually taken and thus which type is being selected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/how-do-i-see-a-c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing-in-visual-studio (assume VS due to the "c4430" error naming style)

Comment: Thanks @mindriot (1) VS 2012. (2) Yes (3) I think so. In theory is defined in tmwtypes...

Comment: @iksemyonov thanks for the link. I am going to review it.